# Why are CSS @page properties not working?

Tags: css, printing, media, specifications

According to the [specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/) for CSS Paged Media, it should be possible to do something like

```css
@media print {
  @page {
    size: a4;
    background: green;
  }
}
```

Evidence for such statement are the [Example 9](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#example-8b37b195) present in the specification and it seems also quite clearly stated in the [Appendix A](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#properties-list).

Unfortunately, though, it seems impossible to accomplish such aim: apparently all the properties are ignored and I cannot get the desires result (setting the background of the page without workarounds).

According to [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40page), the `@page` specification should be all supported from at least Firefox (leaving aside some minor features) and Chromium/Chrome on which I am currently testing such behavior.

Do you have clues or ideas about this weird behavior? Is it possible that the browsers are not currently adhering to the specifications?

**EDIT:** In [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page#description) is clearly specified that properties other than `size` and `margin` are not supported. I still wonder why no one is caring about the specs.

Comment: Use `@page` _outside_ the `@media` block.

Comment: According to the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#page-size-media-query) it is valid and anyway did not bring any benefit

Comment: You linked to the current _Working Draft_ specification - it isn't a standard yet - and to my knowledge, no browsers even implement it yet.

Comment: Secondly, the spec you linked to actually contradicts your presumption: _"If a `size` property declaration is qualified by a [...] media query (or other conditional on the size of the paper), **then the declaration must be ignored**"_ - (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

> According to [the specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/) for CSS Paged Media, it should be possible to do something like

The specification you linked to doesn't suggest that the CSS you've posted is valid, on the contrary, it states (emphasis mine):

> If a `size` property declaration is qualified by a *width, height, device-width, device-height, aspect-ratio, device-aspect-ratio or orientation media query* (or other conditional on the size of the paper), **then the declaration must be ignored**

...this is because...

> […] Media queries do not honor size: they assume the paper size that would be chosen if no `@page` rules were specified.

---

You *can* achieve the effect you want, but not-like-that.

Like so:

```css
@media print {
    :root {
        background-color: green;
        /* Note that most browsers don't print page background colors at all as it looks awful, regardless of if it's inkjet, color-laser, etc */
    }
}

@page {
    size: a4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such suggestions. Unfortunately, though, in this way I cannot apply a different style for the fist page since the properties (e.g. `background`)  assigned to `@page:first` would be ignored.

Comment: Are you intending to use a commodity browser-engine (Chromium, etc?) with your stylesheet? Or are you open to using an engine specifically meant for printing, like PrinceXML? (which is notable for its high-level of support for CSS's printing features)

Comment: I would have liked to use a normal browser and allow a client-side and elegant pdf export of the page

Comment: I cannot recommend that. Browsers are too unpredictable (and slow...). If you need reliable, consistent, and performant HTML+CSS-to-print/PDF then you should use a proper engine like PrinceXML.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used [Paged.js](https://pagedjs.org/documentation/4-how-paged.js-works/) as polyfill go around the issue I had encountered.